# Table Relations sql, php

Tags: mysql, sql, join, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I'm building a database driven management system in php. I've created two separate tables. One table has a list of student names and personal information. The other table is used to store notes. Example: If a student comes in to get advised, the adviser can create one or more notes for the student they're helping. What's the best way to link a note with a student id so the adviser can see the old notes and new notes for the student they're advising: foreign key, inner join, or full outer join?

Comment: Student_id, date, note

Comment: Use a foreign key in the notes table that relates it to the students table.

Answer (score 0):

u askin for this ?
student table : student_id ,student_name
notes table : note_id , student_id, Date, Note